# Incorporar link pra redirecionamento de caixa de pesquisa

Tags: php, javascript

Possuo o link `http://www.algumacoisa.com/d/` 
Preciso de um código onde exista uma caixa de texto, o usuário digita o link e clica "ir" então é direcionado para

```
http://www.algumacoisa.com/d/HTTP://WWW.LINKDOUSUÁRIO.COM
```

No entanto sem banco de dados.
É possível?

Não consegui deixar mais específico pois não encontrei nada parecido ou palavras para descrever o que desejava.

Comment: Coloque o código para facilitar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você precisa somente concatenar o link digitado + sua url, creio que o próprio javascript faça isso:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="link" />
<button id="ir" onclick="ir()">IR</button>
```

**JS**

```
function ir() {
 var link = document.getElementById('link').value;
 var url = "http://www.algumacoisa.com/d/";
 var linktodo = url+link;
 window.open(linktodo, '_blank');
}
```

Pode ficar mais simples utilizando jQuery caso use, se não quiser abrir em outra guia tire o blank.
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Mesmo já possuindo uma resposta correta, vou postar uma sugestão com jQuery, como bem lembrou o próprio amigo que respondeu:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="link" />
<button id="ir">IR</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#ir').click(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://www.algumacoisa.com/d/" + $('#link').val();
    });
});
```